# Downloading CSV_GDX_tools.exe package

Tags: r, package, gams-math

I have to work with GAMS and R to extract data however I am a new R user and never have used GAMS before. I need to download a package called `CSV_GDX_tools.exe` and I have no idea what that is...

When I try to install it in R, I get this error message:

> Warning in install.packages :
>     package ‘CSV_GDX_tools.exe’ is not available (for R version 3.3.2)

Can anyone please help me how and where I can download the package?

Answer (score 0):

First, that does not sound like an R-package, but rather like an outdated utility program for GAMS.
I say outdated, because GAMS now has built-in the functionality to convert GDX (GAMS data files) to CSV files, which can be read by any statistics program including R.
GAMS also gives you the option of exporting your data to an SQLite database file (.db), which can be read by R.

Have a look here:
https://www.gams.com/help/index.jsp?topic=%2Fgams.doc%2Fuserguides%2Fmccarl%2Fgdx_utilities.htm